# swiftui login page does not work after typing username and password

Tags: authentication, swiftui, login-page

I want to go to Content View from Home View as below but it doesn't load.

Below are the code

**Find_my_FriendsApp/@main**

```
@StateObject var authentication = Authentication()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup() {
        
        if authentication.isValidated {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(authentication)
        } else {
            HomeView()
                .environmentObject(authentication)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you intending to change the root view from the App Scene?

Comment: Yes I will change the root view from the App Scene

Comment: You can't do that, you need to present a .fullScreenCover